# How to make tts read text on a page in my app, without a button press

Tags: android, android-studio, text-to-speech

I apologize in advance if I am not asking this correctly or I'm in the wrong section, but this is my first time actually having to post a question on here. I've been trying to create an app that is like a personal assistant that is very verbal. For the time being I am just wanting to read certain response on the screen once the app starts up in the style of chat bubbles. But I need to know how to make tts read the messages without the individual having to press a button or anything of the sort, "Automatically" if that makes any sense. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: TalkBack is an accessibility service. I don't believe this tag applies. The approach for this assuming TalkBack is on, vs it not being on is very different. Please clarify!

Comment: I apologize. It wouldnt be on already. I was only adding the tag to open it up a bit

Comment: Understood.  Marking it as TalkBack just associates it as an "Accessibility" requirement, instead of just a generic requirement.  The question is more clear now!